# What is the purpose of declaring objects with OR conditions?

Tags: javascript

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
```

I understand what above line does. But what's its best use case? Why is this format not used in other languages like Python or PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That kind of code is used to avoid errors about unset variables in the code. Like in this case:

```
function sayHello(name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}

sayHello(); // "Hello undefined"

function lengthOf(obj) {
    return obj.length;
}

lengthOf(); // ReferenceError cannot read property length of undefined
```

You can avoid it by adding a simple line:

```
function sayHello(name) {
    var name = name || "";
    return "Hello " + name;
}

sayHello(); // "Hello "
sayHello("Mike"); // "Hello Mike"

function lengthOf(obj) {
   var obj = obj || [];
   return obj.length;
}

lengthOf(); // 0
lengthOf([1,2,3]); // 3
```

In PHP you can do it by using the `isset()` function:

```
if (!isset($variable)) $variable = "";
```

Now you can use your variable without getting any error or unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

One use case for this is if you have two scripts using the same variable/ns and you want to make sure you only create a new one unless it is already defined.

You can use this to emulate namespaces in javascript:

```
(function(api){

/* private functions here */

api.apiFunction = function(){ /* useful code*/ }

})(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {})
```

Any other script you may load later that you want to be part of the same namespace would then just use the same syntax to append new functionality:

```
(function(api){

/* private functions here */

api.anotherApiFunction = function(){ /* useful code*/ }

})(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {})
```

anotherApiFunction is now appended to the same namespace. You would access both functions like:

```
myNamespace.apiFunction();
myNamespace.anotherApiFunction();
```